# How to add text next to an image inside a div which flips in 3D

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/ax26f966/

HTML:

```
<section id="btn">
    <p>View the Newsletter</p>
    <div id="facebook">

        <div class="logo"><div class="recto"></div></div>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="logo verso"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="shadow"><img src="http://lab.aqro.be/img/shadow.png" alt="shadow" /></div>
</section>
```

How can I add the text `WEBSITE` or something else next to the envelope, so when hovered, it also flips.

Comment: Something close to what I want... https://jsfiddle.net/ax26f966/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**check here : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kr09bz1t/)**

remove `text-indent: -9999px;` from `#facebook` 
and change your html to:

View the Newsletter

```
        <div class="logo">
         <div class="recto">
           <h2>WEBSITE</h2>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="logo verso">
           <h2>WEBSITE</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="shadow"><img src="http://lab.aqro.be/img/shadow.png" alt="shadow" /></div>
</section>
```